# Regex replace: obfuscating phone number

Tags: regex, validation

I've been trying to create a regexp that obfuscates phonen umbers, but having a bit trouble.

Let's say I have phone numbers like

```
123-1231234
123 1231234
123-123 12 12
01555555
```

and I wan't to replace digits with X's AFTER the first - or whitespace, so the result would be

```
123-XXXXXXX
123 XXXXXX
123-XXX XX XX
015XXXXXXX (if there's no whitespace or - then everything after 3rd digit).
```

But being poor in regexp and with great struggle I came up with this expression (-(\d+))|(\s(\d+)) but it gives me only results like 123X

Comment: What language is this? Why does is have to be a regexp? It could be easier without.

Answer (score 0):

```
/([0-9]{3})([0-9 -.]{3,})/g
```

I'd match the 2 pieces (first 3 chars then rest of number), then replace the latter with x's in whatever language you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it in perl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my ($begin, $end) = $_ =~ /^(\d{3}-?)(.*)$/;
    $end =~ s/\d/X/g;
    print $begin . $end, "\n";
}

__DATA__
123-1231234
123 1231234
123-123 12 12
0155555555
```

**output:**

```
123-XXXXXXX
123 XXXXXXX
123-XXX XX XX
015XXXXXXX
```